# Creating charts (charts.js) values coming from SQLite database using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, database, sqlite, chart.js

I'm trying to create a chart. And here is my html code

```
<div class="card">
   <div class="item item-divider">
     Approved and Pending Members 
   </div>
   <div class="item item-text-wrap">
      <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-bar" data="memStatData" labels="status" legend="true" series="stats" options="{showTooltips: true}">       </canvas>
   </div>
</div>
```

and my JS:

```
 $scope.status = ["Approved", "Pending"];
  $scope.stats = ["Stats"];
  $scope.memStatData = [];

  var query = "SELECT sum(members.status='P') as pending, "
  + "sum(members.status='A') as approved FROM members";
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [])
  .then(function(res){
      $scope.memStatData = res.rows.item(0);
      console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.memStatData));
  }, function(err){
      $cordovaToast.showShortBottom('Something Went Wrong').then(function(success){}, function(err){});
      console.log(err.message);
  });
```

How can i display the sum of pending and approved in my chart? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create a bar chart? Take a look at the example usage (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-example-usage), especially the part about datasets and you will see how to feed your data to the chart. Ask a more specific question if you get stuck on that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out already. Let me know if I did it right. But the chart gets values from my database.

```
  $scope.status = ["Approved", "Pending"];
          $scope.stats = ["Stats"];

var query = "SELECT sum(members.status='P') as pending, "
      + "sum(members.status='A') as approved FROM members";
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [])
      .then(function(res){
            $scope.memStatData= res.rows.item(0);
            var p = $scope.memStatData.pending;
            var a = $scope.memStatData.approved;
            console.log(p);
            console.log(a);
            $scope.memStatData = [
                [p, a]
            ];
      }, function(err){
          // $cordovaToast.showShortBottom('Something Went Wrong').then(function(success){}, function(err){});
          console.log(err.message);
      });
```